# Непонимаю как динамически обновлять состояние элемента в блоке RecyclerView

Tags: java, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Класс MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String Data_base = "List";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.id_rv_container);
    RAdapter radapter = new RAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(radapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    Button btncreate = findViewById(R.id.btn_create);
    btncreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String adress = "adress";
            String aname = "name";

            final SharedPreferences.Editor name = getSharedPreferences(Data_base, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            name.remove("list_item_id");
            name.putString(aname, adress);
            name.apply();

            final SPreferenceSG sp_class2 = new SPreferenceSG(v.getContext(),aname);
            sp_class2.set_sp_name(aname);
            sp_class2.set_sp_adress(adress);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Класс RecyclerView:

```
public class RAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String Data_base = "List";

private ArrayList<String> adress_List;
private ArrayList<String> name_List;
private ArrayList<String> last_date;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    ConstraintLayout row;
    TextView name_tv, adress_tv, data_tv;
    ImageView img;
    Button btn_start, btn_settings;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        row = itemView.findViewById(R.id.a_row);
        name_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
        adress_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adress_tv);
        data_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.data_tv);
        img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        btn_start = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        btn_settings = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_settings);
        
        btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                
            }
        });

        btn_settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                //CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog(v.getContext(),name_List.get(pos));
                //customDialog.show();
                name_List.remove(pos);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}

RAdapter(Context context) {
    // Вывести весь список базы SharedPreference
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Data_base, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    adress_List = new ArrayList<>();
    name_List = new ArrayList<>();
    last_date = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPreferences .getAll();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
        //System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
        adress_List.add((String) entry.getValue());
        name_List.add(entry.getKey());

        final SPreferenceSG sp_getter = new SPreferenceSG(context,entry.getKey());

        last_date.add(sp_getter.get_sp_last_backup_date());
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "bind, position = " + i);
    TextView set_name_tv = viewHolder.name_tv;
    set_name_tv.setText(name_List.get(i));

    TextView set_tv = viewHolder.adress_tv;
    set_tv.setText(adress_List.get(i));

    TextView set_last = viewHolder.data_tv;
    set_last.setText(last_date.get(i));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return adress_List.size();
}

@Override
public RAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
}
```

Разметка блока RecycleView:

```
[![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/a_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_mercury"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/img"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/img"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/img"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adress_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Adress"
        android:textColor="@color/white_alpha"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/img"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/img"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_tv"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_backgroung_str_sett"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:textColor="#D6D6D6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/img"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/img"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/img"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/img"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.96" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_start"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_backgroung_str_sett"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textColor="#D6D6D6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_settings"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_settings"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_settings" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="23.12.20 23:45"
        android:textColor="@color/white_alpha"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/img" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_mercury"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/data_tv"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/img" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Progress: %"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="318dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="20dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том что я не понимаю как именно управлять состоянием отдельного элемента в каждом блоке. Т.е. например нажатием кнопки Start я хочу управлять поведением элемента в том же самом блоке где и была нажата кнопка. Конкретно нужно менять в реальном времени состояние элемента "Progress: %" на экране. По нажатию на кнопку Start будет запускаться фоновый процесс и его статус отражаться в поле "Progress:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну можно всю логику вашего элемента recycler view определить в методе onBindViewHolder вашего адаптера. В качестве примера я вам немного сократил его, убрав лишнее и добавил обработчик нажатия для вашей кнопки START. Сейчас по нажатию в поле name ставится строчка "Hello". Думаю дальше по аналогии разберетесь. Тут ничего сложного. Если что пишите.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

viewHolder.name_tv.setText(name_List.get(i));

viewHolder.adress_tv.setText(adress_List.get(i));

viewHolder.data_tv.setText(last_date.get(i));

holder.btn_start.setOnClickListener(() -> {
     holder.name_tv.setText("Hello);
 })
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Бился не одну неделю, вы очень помогли. Все сработало.

Comment: был рад помочь!